# What's the best way to check if an application is running in bash?

Tags: bash, grep, ps

Should I pipe `ps -ax | grep <name> | grep -q <longername>`, or is there a nicer method?  
 PS, the second grep in my example is to remove the first `grep` process from the output. 

Thanks

Comment: Use `grep [m]yapp` instead of `grep myapp` to avoid matching the `grep` command in the output of `ps`.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux there exists a command for that, it is called `pgrep`. On Ubuntu it is in the package `procps` together with `pkill`.